¿Como añadir una categoria cuando creas un producto en un formulario reactivo en angular 17?
Tengo Frontend y backend(controlador category con id y name). Cuando en el formulario creo un producto para añadirlo al listado, no sé como añadirle la categoría a la que quiero que pertenezca.
Esto parte del código de TypeScript. He eliminado del código insertar las fotos y mostrar el mensaje de confirmación.
He intentado poner una casilla de categoría en el formulario pero no sé como asignarle el id de categoría que tengo en la tabla de mySql.
Quiero que se asigne la categoría al crear el producto, porque en el home quiero filtrar el producto por categoría, pero al no asignarse el id al crear el producto no puedo filtrarlo.
export class VestidosFormComponent implements OnInit {
  category: Category | undefined;
  vestido: Vestido | undefined;
  categories: Category[] = [];

  vestidosForm = new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(),
  });

  vestidos: Vestido | undefined;
  isUpdate: boolean = false;
  isDelete: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadCategories();

    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      let id = params['id'];
      if (!id)
        return;

      this.httpClient.get<Vestido>(`http://localhost:3000/vestidos/${id}`)
        .subscribe(vestido => {
          this.isUpdate = true

          this.vestidosForm.reset({
            id: vestido.id,
            model: vestido.model,
          });
        });
    });

    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      let id = params['id'];
      if (id)
        this.httpClient.get<Vestido>(`http://localhost:3000/vestidos/${id}`)
          .subscribe(vestido => {
            this.isDelete = true
          });
    });
  }

  loadCategories(): void {
    this.httpClient.get<Category[]>('http://localhost:3000/category')
      .subscribe(categories => {
        this.categories = categories;
      });
  }

  save(): void {
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('id', this.vestidosForm.get('id')?.value ?? 0);
    formData.append('model', this.vestidosForm.get('model')?.value ?? '');

    if (this.isUpdate) {
      const id = this.vestidosForm.get('id')?.value;
      this.httpClient.put<Vestido>(`http://localhost:3000/vestidos/${id}`, formData)
        .subscribe(vestido => {
          this.vestidos = vestido;
          this.category = this.category;
        });

    } else {
      this.httpClient.post<Vestido>('http://localhost:3000/vestidos', formData)
        .subscribe(vestido => {
          this.vestidos = vestido;
        });
    }
  }
}


Comparte el código que tienes.

Este código necesita mucho trabajo, aparte de que estas haciendo las peticiones Http directamente en el componente cuando deberían de hacerse un servicio como se indica en la documentación de Angular. Ya probaste el backend con Postman y confirmaste que si funciona?

Hay fallas en las bases de programación, JavaScript y TypeScript/Angular, los errores que veo son:

Solamente defines id en vestidosForm pero luego intentas usar model y category. No se como esperas que acceda a dichos campos.
Tienes this.category = this.category; que no hace nada, le asignas su mismo valor, hay que repasar el concepto de contexto this.
En ngOnInit() te suscribes doblemente a this.activatedRoute.params, puede producir algún comportamiento no deseado.
En base al punto anterior, en la segunda suscripción al hacer la petición no haces nada con ella.
En save() creas un nuevo FormData sin usar el form que ya tenías declarado... tendrías que cambiarlo por algo así const formData = this.vestidosForm.form.value
No tienes ningún manejo de errores, en el caso de las peticiones HTTP eso lo tienes que tener en el servicio para evitar repetir el código en otros componentes donde uses dicho servicio (principio D.R.Y)

Esperando a saber si el backend funciona, te dejo primero el código que debería de ir en el servicio. El comando para crear un servicio es ng g s y le pones nombre igual como si fuera un componente. Adjunto código:
Servicio:
export class DressService {
  private readonly baseUrl: string = "http://localhost:3000/vestidos";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private errorHandler(error: any) {
    return throwError(() => error);
  }

  getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<Category[]>(this.baseUrl)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

  getById(id: string): Observable<Vestido> {
    return this.http
      .get<Vestido>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

  create(vestido: Vestido) {
    return this.http
      .post<Vestido>(this.baseUrl, vestido)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

  update(vestido: Vestido) {
    return this.http
      .put<Vestido>(`${this.baseUrl}/${vestido.id}`, vestido)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

  delete(id: string) {
    return this.http
      .delete<Vestido>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
}

Aquí te recomiendo crear una interface para la respuesta del backend, ya que si esperas que te regrese el objeto de vestido entero pues no hace mucho sentido, por ejemplo podrías enviar un mensaje tipo "Vestido actualizado" o "Vestido eliminado" seguido del ID y usar dicho mensaje para enviar una alerta que al usuario.
